# How to specify NONE partition key for deleting a document in Document DB java SDK?

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I have only a single collection and when I try to delete the document using the code below

```
    PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey("undefined");
    RequestOptions requestOptions=new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.setPartitionKey(partitionKey);
    for(Document currentDocument: existingIMEIDevice){
        try {
            ConfigVariables.documentClient.deleteDocument(currentDocument.getSelfLink(), requestOptions);
        } catch (DocumentClientException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

it throws exception.

> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["Resource Not Found"]}
>   ActivityId: 4353e7c0-0b24-4b2a-8ec6-fc2db4059aa0, Request URI: /apps/708ed403-166f-44e4-847f-ccaa0cd22d9c/services/d1e2ed4d-7e69-4a3d-9575-3e24b96621b4/partitions/e3fc6138-06a5-4876-a629-a4be69917ded/replicas/131533416718986721p, StatusCode: NotFound
>       at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.internal.ErrorUtils.maybeThrowException(ErrorUtils.java:69)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.internal.GatewayProxy.performDeleteRequest(GatewayProxy.java:187)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.internal.GatewayProxy.doDelete(GatewayProxy.java:99)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.internal.GatewayProxy.processMessage(GatewayProxy.java:332)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient$7.apply(DocumentClient.java:2877)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.internal.RetryUtility.executeDocumentClientRequest(RetryUtility.java:58)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.doDelete(DocumentClient.java:2883)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.deleteDocument(DocumentClient.java:956)
>       at com.moveinsync.centraldevices.persistance.AzureCommDAOImpl.replaceDocument(AzureCommDAOImpl.java:45)
>       at com.moveinsync.centraldevices.persistance.AzureCommDAOImpl.documentDbBulkInsert(AzureCommDAOImpl.java:85)
>       at com.moveinsync.centraldevices.jobs.ToAzureJob.executeInternal(ToAzureJob.java:27)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
>       at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
>       at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
>   If I do not provide RequestOptions it asks me to provide a partition key.
>   I don't have a partition key as the below does not returns anything

```
SELECT c.partitionKey FROM c ORDER BY c.partitionKey
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: When you created the document, did you specify a value for partitionKey attribute? If so, what's that value?

Comment: No, I didn't. I already mentioned that.                                                               SELECT c.partitionKey FROM c ORDER BY c.partitionKey                  this query returns nothing. I don't have any partition key in my collection as of now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per my experience, if your collection does not have a partitioning key, you do not need to set the query criteria for the partitioning key when you operate the database.

In you post, the collection does not have a partitioning key, and you set the partitioning key into RequestOption. So , the database certainly doesn't know where to find the document to operate.

You could refer to my snippet of code:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.*;

public class DeleteDocuments {
    private static String accountName="https://jay.documents.azure.com:443/";

    private static String accountKey="Czi66skfjZYLTaXuDhoxNb2JHL4DR98VxAxGXtLkWFnjCa5e7gUXQuPgemlXwyPWjjWJpwrseH1wPMfhkqA8cQ==";

    private static String databaseName = "db";

    private static String collectionName = "coll";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentClientException {

        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
                accountName,
                accountKey
                , new ConnectionPolicy(),
                ConsistencyLevel.Session);

        FeedOptions options = null;
        String sql = "select * from c";
        FeedResponse<Document> queryResults  = client.queryDocuments("dbs/"+databaseName+"/colls/"+collectionName, sql, options);

        System.out.println("before delete :");
        for (Document d : queryResults.getQueryIterable()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("\tRead %s", d));
        }

        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.setOfferThroughput(400);

        client.deleteDocument("/dbs/"+databaseName+"/colls/"+collectionName+"/docs/1",requestOptions);

        queryResults  = client.queryDocuments("dbs/"+databaseName+"/colls/"+collectionName, sql, options);


        System.out.println("after delete :");

        for (Document d : queryResults.getQueryIterable()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("\tRead %s", d));
        }
    }
}
```

---

***Update Answer:***

I think you misunderstand the meaning of `partitionkey` property in the `options[]`.

For example , my container is created like this:

[image]

The partition key is "name" for my collection here. You could check your collection's partition key.

And my documents as below :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "jay"
}

{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "jay2"
}
```

My `partitionkey` is **'name'**, so here I have two paritions : **'jay'** and **'jay1'**.

So, here you should set the `partitionkey` property to 'jay' or 'jay2',not 'name'.

At this point, if I run the code below without setting partition key into RequestOptions, I'll meet the same issue as you.

```
  RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
  requestOptions.setOfferThroughput(400);

        client.deleteDocument("/dbs/"+databaseName+"/colls/"+collectionName+"/docs/1",requestOptions);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.addPartitionKeyInformation(DocumentClient.java:3199)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.addPartitionKeyInformation(DocumentClient.java:3180)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.deleteDocument(DocumentClient.java:959)
>     at DeleteDocuments.main(DeleteDocuments.java:32)

I need to set partition key parameter to be the partition where the operated document stored.

```
 RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
 requestOptions.setOfferThroughput(400);
 PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey("jay");
 requestOptions.setPartitionKey(partitionKey);

        client.deleteDocument("/dbs/"+databaseName+"/colls/"+collectionName+"/docs/1",requestOptions);
```

---

***Update Answer 2:***

I guess you want to operate the document which does not set partition key.

Please refer to this perfect [blog](http://blog.lytzen.name/2016/12/find-docs-with-no-partitionkey-in-azure.html), you'll find the answer!

In java code , just set partition key to `Undefined.Value()` then everything will be done.

```
 RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
 requestOptions.setOfferThroughput(400);
 PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value());
 requestOptions.setPartitionKey(partitionKey);

        client.deleteDocument("/dbs/"+databaseName+"/colls/"+collectionName+"/docs/3",requestOptions);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I already tried doing this, but it throws exception                                                      2017-11-02 11:16:06 DEBUG DocumentClient:951 - Deleting a Document. documentLink: [dbs/5Ck4AA==/colls/5Ck4ALpusQA=/docs/5Ck4ALpusQABAAAAAAAAAA==/]
2017-11-02 11:16:09 ERROR JobRunShell:211 - Job com.hassan.temp.toAzureJob threw an unhandled Exception: 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.

Comment: @SyedHassanAshraf it seems that your collection already has a partition key. However , you said you don't have any partition key in your collection in your reply comment. So, I'm little confused. Would you please post the screenshots of your database structure?

Comment: @SyedHassanAshraf In addition, please post some sample documents you stored in your database.

Comment: I can't do that. I am not allowed to. But you could tell me how to verify or check if my collection already has a partition key? That would be of great help.

Comment: Okay, I understand that what should be the value fo partition key attribute in RequestOptions, but suppose if I have a collection with fields as {name, class, city, company,...} and somebody else has created the partition and filled it. Now how to know which one is the PartitionKey here as in your case it was "name". The thing is that I was given only the read/write keys and the database and the collection link. How to know if there is a partition key(like "name") in my collection(and if not then what to do).

Comment: @SyedHassanAshraf  You could get the collection's partition key via the code below: DocumentCollection collection=client.readCollection("/dbs/"+databaseName+"/colls/"+collectionName,null).getResource();
        System.out.println(collection.getPartitionKey());

Comment: @SyedHassanAshraf If the collection does not have any partition key ,then you just operation the documents without setting any partition key parameters.

Comment: I see two columns Id(list of ids) and BUSINESSUNITID(here all values are undefined)  So, I guss that BUSINESSUNITID is my partition key and I should write something like RequestOptions rops = new RequestOptions(new PartitionKey("undefined"))                Is that correct?          But doing this, it throws an error           Request URI: /apps/708ed403-166f-44e4-847f-ccaa0cd22d9c/services/d1e2ed4d-7e69-4a3d-9575-3e24b96621b4/partitions/e3fc6138-06a5-4876-a629-a4be69917ded/replicas/131533416718986721p, StatusCode: NotFound

Comment: @SyedHassanAshraf  Please see my update answer 2.Thanks !

Comment: Thank You. It worked. You have been of great help. The thing is that I was using "undefined" instead of Undefined.value(). I saw an answer on stack overflow and the person told that if the partitionkey is not defined then you have to pass a string as "undefined". But still, thank you. For being so patient and quick. :)

Comment: @SyedHassanAshraf That's all right.Have a nice day!