# What does getContext.getCollection() return in CosmosDB stored procedure?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have written a simple stored procedure to query a collection and return response but when I execute it as node.js script I get `400` error code and following error message:

> "PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header"

When `getContext().getCollection.getSelfLink()` value is printed I get `dbs/3Mk0AA==/colls/3Mk0AOWMbw0=/` but my database and collection Ids are some other values.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: getSelfLink prints the system generated IDs, so that's probably not the issue. Can you include the source code for the stored procedure? Are you passing in the partition key in the request headers?

Answer (score 1):

When you observe the documents you created in Azure Cosmos DB, you will see several system generated properties in addition to the ID you set.

You could find official statement from [System vs. user defined resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-resources).

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "statusId": "new",
    "_rid": "duUuAN3LzQEIAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/duUuAA==/colls/duUuAN3LzQE=/docs/duUuAN3LzQEIAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"0400d4ee-0000-0000-0000-5a24ac3f0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1512352831
}
```

`getContext().getCollection.getSelfLink()` method returns `"_self"` value, not `Id` value you set.

> PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified
>   in the header

This issue should be due to you set the PartitionKey incorrectly.

Suppose your partitioning key is `color` and there are two partitions `red` and `blue` in the database. The PK should be set `red` or `blue`, not `color`.

You could refer to a similar thread I answered before : [How to specify NONE partition key for deleting a document in Document DB java SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049593/how-to-specify-none-partition-key-for-deleting-a-document-in-document-db-java-sd/47066751#47066751)

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Thanks for the help guys!!

Incase anyone else tries, adding partition key while executing the stored procedure worked for me. The code is,

```
client.executeStoredProcedure('/dbs/<database-id>/colls/<collection-id>/sprocs/<storedproc-id>', <input to the procedure(if any)>, { partitionKey: <partition-field-id> }, callback);
```