# Why would a Cosmos stored procedure run differently when called from browser vs. called from Java?

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

I have a stored procedure in Cosmos DB Emulator. All this procedure does is: delete ALL documents from `mycollection`.  When I run it in browser (`https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html`), it works great. Then I try to call it from Java:

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions(); 
requestOptions.setPartitionKey(new PartitionKey(null));
System.out.println("START DELETE PROCEDURE"); 
StoredProcedureResponse spr = client.executeStoredProcedure(sprocLink, requestOptions, null);     
System.out.println(spr.getResponseAsString());
```

And get the following result: `{"deleted": 0,"continuation": false}`

This is CRAZY. I'm running this stored procedure from the browser and getting this result: `{"deleted": 10,"continuation": false}`. Then (of course adding back those 10 documents)  running this result from Java and getting this result: `{"deleted": 0,"continuation": false}`

**So when the stored procedure is ran by Java, it is called but didn't do the job. Deleted nothing.... Why would this happen?**

---

Below is the stored procedure

```
   function testStoredProcedure( ) {
       var collection = getContext().getCollection();
        var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
        var response = getContext().getResponse();
        var responseBody = {
            deleted: 0,
            continuation: true
        };

        var query = 'SELECT * FROM mycollection   ';

    // Validate input.
    if (!query) throw new Error("The query is undefined or null.");

    tryQueryAndDelete();

    // Recursively runs the query w/ support for continuation tokens.
    // Calls tryDelete(documents) as soon as the query returns documents.
    function tryQueryAndDelete(continuation)) {
        var requestOptions = {continuation: continuation};

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, function (err, retrievedDocs, responseOptions) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (retrievedDocs.length > 0) {
                // Begin deleting documents as soon as documents are returned form the query results.
                // tryDelete() resumes querying after deleting; no need to page through continuation tokens.
                //  - this is to prioritize writes over reads given timeout constraints.
                tryDelete(retrievedDocs);
            } else if (responseOptions.continuation) {
                // Else if the query came back empty, but with a continuation token; repeat the query w/ the token.
                tryQueryAndDelete(responseOptions.continuation);
            } else {
                // Else if there are no more documents and no continuation token - we are finished deleting documents.
                responseBody.continuation = false;
                response.setBody(responseBody);
            }
        });

        // If we hit execution bounds - return continuation: true.
        if (!isAccepted) {
            response.setBody(responseBody);
        }
    }

    // Recursively deletes documents passed in as an array argument.
    // Attempts to query for more on empty array.
    function tryDelete(documents) {
        if (documents.length > 0) {
            // Delete the first document in the array.
            var isAccepted = collection.deleteDocument(documents[0]._self, {}, function (err, responseOptions) {
                if (err) throw err;

                responseBody.deleted++;
                documents.shift();
                // Delete the next document in the array.
                tryDelete(documents);
            });

            // If we hit execution bounds - return continuation: true.
            if (!isAccepted) {
                response.setBody(responseBody);
            }
        } else {
            // If the document array is empty, query for more documents.
            tryQueryAndDelete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You included your Java code, but... I'm not sure what you mean when you say you "run it in the browser." How are you executing your stored procedure from the browser? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Thank you. I mean `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator` console `https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

For partitioned containers, when executing a stored procedure, a partition key value must be provided in the request options. Stored procedures are always scoped to a partition key. Items that have a different partition key value will not be visible to the stored procedure. This also applied to triggers as well.

You are setting partition key to "null" in requestOptions. "null" is a valid partition key value. Looks like "null" is not a partition key value for your 10 documents.

Comment: thank you. but when i execute stored procedure from browser, click `Execute`, then the emulator asks for `Partition key value` and `Enter input parameters (if any)`. I leave those as blank, and it works!!! So don't see why the same stored procedure would fail when running from Java. But anyway, yes there is a partition key, and i tried feeding it to Java code. However, the same result. It runs, but doesn't delete documents.

Comment: so are you passing partition key value to requestOptions.setPartitionKey(new PartitionKey(<PKVALUE>); ?

Answer (score -1):

Humbly reposting @Jay Gong answer [How to specify NONE partition key for deleting a document in Document DB java SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049593/how-to-specify-none-partition-key-for-deleting-a-document-in-document-db-java-sd)

Maybe it will help someone. Put:

`PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value());`